# Insert an item into for loop using each_with_index, instead of replacing

Tags: ruby

Most marketplace website's nowadays have an ad partial injected into the middle of the list, giving users a form to sign up.

[image]

Looking to get a better understanding into how `each_with_index` works and the correct way to insert a `div` into a list of objects. Let's take a list of, say 10 boxing studios, and using the below code we inject a `div` into the middle of the list. How do you inject a div without replacing the record entirely?

Expected: the 10 boxing studios with new div in the 6th position (11 items in the list in total)

Actual: 9 boxing studios with the new div replacing one of the boxing studios in the 6th position

```
@list.each_with_index do |item, idx|
  if((idx + 1) % 6 == 0)
    # Insert ad partial
  else
  # Print out each object in the list
  end
end
```

Comment: I fail to see here how your code is "replacing" anything, can you show the rest of the code? How are you inserting the ad partiall or printing the objects in the list?

Comment: Sorry - typically, there are 10 records printed out in the list (10 boxing locations). However, using the `each_with_index` in the manner I outlined above the actual behaviour is 10 records returned where the 6th one is the ad partial....the expected behaviour would be 11 records returned (the original 10 boxing locations and the one inserted partial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the variables

```
@list = (1..10).map { |n| "item #{n}"}
#=> ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6", "item 7", "item 8", "item 9", "item 10"]

@signup = 'signup form'
position = 6
```

You can iterate and print the element to be inserted without modifying the array:

```
@list.each_with_index do |item, idx|
  p @signup if position == idx + 1 # render the form
  p item
end

# "item 1"
# "item 2"
# "item 3"
# "item 4"
# "item 5"
# "signup form"
# "item 6"
# "item 7"
# "item 8"
# "item 9"
# "item 10"
```

Comment: Thanks @iGian, this is the expected behaviour

Comment: I believe my issue was the if/else statement which cause the replacement rather than a simple if guard to insert

Comment: Using `if then else` as you did, apart the kind of condition, when the condition is true you are skipping the related item ( = the form replaces that item).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
> list = [1,2,3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
> list[1...1] = 0 # insert at position 1
> list
#⇒ [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

Insert it each 6th position:

```
list = [1] * 15
(5...list.size).step(6) { |i| list[i...i] = 0 }
list
#⇒ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```